# Embeddin PHP into Javascript ,Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, php

```
I am getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
on line : TableX[i] = <?php echo $TableX[$x];  ?> ;
In the code below :
 index.php

for( i = 1 ; i<= <?php echo $num;?> ; i++) 
        {
            <?php for($x = 1 ; $x<=$num ; $x++ ) { ?>
            TableX[i] = <?php echo $TableX[$x];  ?> ;
            TableY[i] = <?php echo $TableY[$x];  ?> ;
        }
        <?php } ?>
```

I've wasted enough time on this , help would be really appreciated .

Comment: Are you getting that syntax error from PHP (at the server) or JS (on the browser console)? If the latter, is PHP enabled at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just output a php array as JSON:

```
<script>
var TableX = <?php echo json_encode($TableX);?>
```

Comment: var TableX = <?php echo json_encode($TableX);?> ;
  var TableY=<?php echo json_encode($TableY);?> ;
  for(i = 1 ; i <= <?php echo $num ;?>; i++)
  {divToAdd = $("<div></div>");
  $(divToAdd).addClass('dragged1');
  $(divToAdd).offset({ left:TableX[i] , top:TableY[i]}) ;
  $('#frame').append(divToAdd);
  }
It looks like there is syntax error in offset() , since when I run it , it does not take values rather it treats it as a text . 
guide me with this ...